# How to replace a repeated character with ascending numbers with python?

Tags: python, replace, text-editor

I am not knowledgable at Python but I am editing a large text file where a character "X" appears many times and I need to replace it with "1" the first time, "2", the second time, etc. It would look like this.

```
Hi X, my name is X, I have X cats.
```

This would become

```
Hi 1, my name is 2, I have 3 cats.
```

The actual file has hundreds of instances of X.

I have been looking this up online for like an hour but I don't understand what people are saying.

Comment: There is more than one way to do this. Seeing the code you've written so far would help narrow the choices. You could use a for loop that reads each character and appends to a list. This gives you the opportunity to also have a variable to use for counting. Compare to "X" and substitute the next count value converted to a string.